# How to redirect all HTTP traffic to a proxy server?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I am looking to redirect all HTTP traffic to a proxy server and the these iptables commands doesn't work:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp –dport 80 -j DNAT –to-destination 10.0.0.1:3128
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp –dport 80 -j REDIRECT –to-ports 3128
```

Error message:

```
iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): unknown option "-m"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your commands:

1. `-m tcp` is not needed.
2. dport is an option for `-p tcp`, and suboptions like this need to be specified with double dashes: `--dport`

Also, for your purpose, only second command is needed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I edited to "iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp  -–dport 80 -j REDIRECT –to-ports 3128" and still receive an error: "iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): unknown option "-p""